# Access to a certain part of JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So i have this JSON:

```
{
  "id_u":"1",
  "nombre_usuario":"JESUS",
  "apellido_paterno_usuario":"DIAZ"
}
```

I just want to access to the fields names

> id_u,_nombre_usuario,apellido_paterno_usuario

And then, create an array with that info.

How can i do that?

Thanks guys

Comment: did you try `object["apellido_paterno_usuario"]`

Answer (score 2):

Do this way :

```
var keyValuePair = {
  "id_u":"1",
  "nombre_usuario":"JESUS",
  "apellido_paterno_usuario":"DIAZ"
};

var arr =new Array();
for (key in keyValuePair){
arr.push(key); // for keys
// arr.push(keyValuePair[key]); // for values
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working but i dont understand the code.

What does it mean the  "K in A" ?

Comment: We just fetching every key, we can write "key in a"

Comment: @user3444889, `for(key in keyValuePair) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to parse JSON.

Try this:

```
var keyArray = [];
var a = {
  "id_u":"1",
  "nombre_usuario":"JESUS",
  "apellido_paterno_usuario":"DIAZ"
};

$.each(a,function(i,v){
    keyArray.push(i); // i is json key and v is json value.
});
console.log(keyArray);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78vRc/)**

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(jsonObject)` is enough.